# SQL query works in Workbench, but not in Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, group-by, sql-order-by

I've got a query:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') as x, COUNT(created_at) as y FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12;
```

It works in MySQL Workbench, but when I paste query in Laravel using `DB::select();` return error below:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'user.table.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by (SQL: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') as x, COUNT(created_at) as y FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12;)
```

When I delete `ORDER BY id DESC` it works perfectly, but I need to reverse table and select only 12 last rows. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Also select the ID in your query, not just `x` and `y`.

Comment: i cant. This data will json encoded and pass to Morris.js linechart, but I've aleady solved my problem. I added id to GROUP BY statement, and it works!

Comment: try DB::raw(), if you want perform whole query. if you use DB::select(), you cant insert whole query in it

Comment: Please post your laravel code. Thats better to understand where you might be losing within code

Comment: It's solved. Here is my code -> $data = json_encode(DB::select("SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m') as x, COUNT(created_at) as y FROM table GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created_at,'%Y-%m'), id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 12;"));

Answer (score 0):

You're using group by , and with group by your ids are different and will not select in this query.
You can use order by x